# get certificate expiry date in unix time (or any other numeric) format

Tags: certificate, openssl

This is needed to compare to current time and see how much is left.

I investigated the matters and it seems people are inventing scripts getting date/time in text from the openssl output, converting it into some form to compare (unix timestamp). I also learnt that certificates themselves contain the date in kind of unit timestamp format in UTC timezone.

So what is the deal of getting this information directly from the certificate instead of having it converted into the human readable format and then converted back to a number?

I do not see such option in openssl application.

What is the easiest way to get number of (let's say) seconds of cert time left without going into such a mess taking time and computing power and requiring questionably portable scripts?

Edit: thanks for the comment. I am working with the embedded platform (openwrt), there's no browser and no user interface, only command line. Certificates are just set of .pem files stored locally. Check will be performed using scripts - and the result will be sent in binary through another channel for the monitoring.

I can do `openssl x509 -in cert.pem -enddate -noout` and then parse out the text, convert it to number etc but it is ugly to say the least.

Comment: The browser can show the expiry date of a certificate. Please add more details about where are stored these certificates and in what format and what is your OS?

Comment: @harrymc thanks, added.

Comment: Why isn't `openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in file.pem` enough? Or is this question about converting the output to another format, and which format? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297853/how-to-determine-ssl-cert-expiration-date-from-a-pem-encoded-certificate)

Comment: the question is exactly about getting the time value as a number (e.g. unix time) out of the certificate. Why this interface/API is missing? Why it only outputs as text timestamp? Of course if there're no alternatives I will go this way...

Comment: We can't answer here "why" questions, we only do "how" questions.

Comment: ok, these questions are actually kind of interrelated. so how can we get - in the first place - date as unix time, without applying the scripts for conversion? not possible?

Comment: @Anonymous - If you want unix timestamp you will have to convert it to unix timestamp yourself.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, do you say there's no other way (at least right now) getting the numeric time value from openssl or any other cert-related processing tools? I have asked question to ensure I did not miss anything obvious (and not so obvious).

Answer (score 0):

`-enddate` outputs in rfc_822 standard by default, so GNU `date` command can read it if you cut `notAfter=` characters:

```
$ openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in cert.pem | cut -c10- | date +%s -f -

1868282453
```

Newer versions of OpenSSL support printing in `-dateopt iso_8601` format, which is at least alphabetically sortable

---

OpenSSL does have a seconds-till-expired check built in, but it's a true/false output:

```
$ openssl x509 -checkend 2592000 -noout -in cert.pem || echo "cert expires in 30 days!"
```